# Clickable ImageButton in RecyclerView

Tags: android, imagebutton, clickable

I have an ImageButton such as this icon [image]. I want when I click on it, it will be like this[image] and when I click again it will  be like picture 1. What should i add to code? These ImageButtons are in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

inside OnBindView().

```
   boolean beforeClicked =false;

   holder.imageView.setOnClickLisnter(new OnClickListner(){

       if(!beforeClicked){
          holder.imageView.setDrawableResource(R.layout.whiteHeart);
          beforeClicked = true; 
       }

       else{
          holder.imageView.setDrawableResource(R.layout.blackHeart);
          beforeClicked = false; 
      }
    });
```

May have some spelling mistakes. You can rectify that.

Comment: it work for first time and after that heart doesn't white.

Comment: Where did declared this  boolean beforeClicked =false;

Comment: inside OnBindViewHolder().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Define Global Variable
Boolean isCheck =  true;

//On click of icon
isCheck =! isCheck // This will make boolean switch like On/Off

if(isCheck){
  //Add your fill icon here
}else{
  //Add your un-filled icon here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add button inside your recycler view item and add one flag into your model class So, when you click first time change image to second one(filled heart) and set flag as true and when click on second time go for your like image code.

So,your code structure will shows like below

Your **model** class

```
public class model {

    private boolean isFirstTime = false;

    ...

    public boolean isFirstTime() {
        return isFirstTime;
    }

    public void setFirstTime(boolean firstTime) {
        isFirstTime = firstTime;
    }

    ...
}
```

Add below code into your **adapter**

```
holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!arrayList.get(position).getIsClick()) {
            holder.yourImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.secondImage));
            arrayList.get(position).setIsClick(true);
        } else {
            //your like image code
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Are you check my answer?

Comment: What issue generated?